# WPF DataVisualization Stacked Column Chart Binding

Tags: wpf, charts

i will generate Stacked column chart, which will display on the x-axis cities and on the y-axis are count of genders in column. How to binding chart and this data:

```
 List<Cities> Cities = new List<Cities>()
    {
        new Cities
        {
            Name = "Paris",
            Genders = new Genders()
            {
                Man = 350000,
                Woman = 436000
            }
        },
        new Cities()
        {
            Name = "London",
            Genders = new Genders()
            {
                Man = 698056,
                Woman = 736982
            }
        }
    };
```

I am trying to generate Series:

```
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var city in Cities)
        {
            Series s1 = new ColumnSeries();
            s1.Title = city.Name;
            s1.Name = "S"+i;
            StackedColumnChart.Series.Add(s1);
            i++;
        }
```

i dont know how to binding data. Thanks

Comment: It depends on a WPF control you will use to display chart. Usually, for binding you need to use `ObservableCollection<Series>` for `StackedColumnChart.Series` and bind to them in your XAML through `ItemsSource="{Binding Series}"`

Comment: You showed me how to use on my example ?

Comment: A good example of charting is on [Sparrow Toolkit](https://sparrowtoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Create%20a%20Basic%20Chart&referringTitle=SparrowChart). See WPF - method 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to download a trial version of [LightningChart](http://arction.com/products_lc_ultimate_sdk) with included demonstration examples for WinForms, WPF with Non-bindable, Semibindable and Fully Bindable examples.

[image]

You can easily look at the source code examples, e.g. ExampleStackedBars.

In a code behind you can create a field, which will be binded to the chart BarSeriesCollection property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BarSeriesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "BarSeries",
            typeof(BarSeriesCollection),
            typeof(ExampleStackedBars)
        );

    public BarSeriesCollection BarSeries
    {
        get { return GetValue(BarSeriesProperty) as BarSeriesCollection; }
        set { SetValue(BarSeriesProperty, value); }
    }
```

And after create a new instance and add data to the collection:

```
BarSeries = new BarSeriesCollection();
GenerateData();
```

In XAML you can easily bind it using this line:

```
<lcusb:LightningChartUltimate.ViewXY>
            **<lcusb:ViewXY BarSeries="{Binding BarSeries}">**
                <lcusb:ViewXY.BarViewOptions>
                    <lcusb:BarViewOptions BarSpacing="30" Grouping="ByIndexFitWidth" Stacking="Stack" IndexGroupingFitGroupDistance="20"/>
                </lcusb:ViewXY.BarViewOptions>
            </lcusb:ViewXY>
        </lcusb:LightningChartUltimate.ViewXY>
</lcusb:LightningChartUltimate>
```

or set binding path in the property tree
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Example in [Sparrow toolkit](https://sparrowtoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Create%20a%20Basic%20Chart&referringTitle=SparrowChart) is for other chart type. i need Stacked bar chart. My graph must in x-axis cities and for each city must be multiple values in column. This is my chart:

```
 <charting:Chart
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            x:Name="StackedColumnChart"
            Title="Stacked Column"
            Margin="5">
        <charting:StackedColumnSeries>
        </charting:StackedColumnSeries>
    </charting:Chart>
```

I dont know what is series. Series is columns? How to assign multiple value (in my example genders) to one column?